# Unknown timestamp reference date

Tags: windows, date, timestamp, epoch

I'm currently dealing with a system which uses an unknown timestamp mechanism.

The system is running on a Windows machine, so my first thought was that it uses some kind of Windows epoch for its timestamps, but it appears it does not.

My goal is to convert these timestamps to Unix timestamps.

---

#### A few examples:

The following timestamp: `2111441659` converts to: `2013-10-01 11:59`

- `2111441998` to `2013-10-01 17:14`
- `2111443876` to `2013-10-02 14:36`
- `2111444089` to `2013-10-02 17:57`

(All dates are GMT+2)

I've tried to calculate the reference date using the data above, but somehow I get a different result with every single timestamp.

Could anybody shed some light on this rather odd problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In your examples, you are not converting to Unix timestamp but rather to DateTime. A timestamp is still an integer. Also, DateTimes depend on things like timezones, DST and the like. Posting a more consistent example would help you and others deal with the real problem.

Comment: I know I'm not converting to Unix timestamps, because after all that's the problem; I do not know how to convert them to Unix timestamps since I don't know the reference date of these timestamps. ;-)

Comment: A DateTime alone is not enough to calculate the timestamp. Saying for example that _`2111441659` converts to: `2013-10-01 11:59 **UTC**`_ is different from, say, _`2111441659` converts to: `2013-10-01 11:59 **EST**`_. They would correspond to different Unix timestamps. My point: _There's insufficient information!_

Comment: The dates in the example are all GMT+2  (UTC)

Comment: I'm actually a bit confused about it, because I've looked at an UTC world map, and my country (The Netherlands) appears to be in UTC 0, I assume you have to take summer/winter time into account, so that would be UTC+1? And now I'm even more confused, haha. (Never worked with UTC before).

Comment: Nevertheless, I think I spotted an inconsistency in your data. Let me doublecheck to be sure, and I'll prepare an elaborate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, after many hours of comparing the timestamps with the datetimes, trying to discover the logic between them, I've found the answer by reverse engineering the software which generates the timestamps.

It turns out that the integer timestamps are actually bitwise representations* of the datetimes.

In pseudocode:

```
year = TimeStamp >> 20;

month = (TimeStamp >> 16) & 15;

day = (TimeStamp >> 11) & 31;

hour = (TimeStamp >> 6) & 31;

minute = TimeStamp & 63;
```

---

**I'm not sure if this is the correct term for it, if not, please correct me.*

Answer (score 0):

To me the number seems to small to be milliseconds. My first guess was then seconds but looking at the speed this number varies with i think minutes is a better guess. Doing some math on it 2111441659/60/24/365 = 4017.20254756 which suggests the epoch might be sometime in the year -2000?

[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_%28reference_date%29#Notable_epoch_dates_in_computing) is a list of common epochs in computing but the year -2000 is not really there :) How are you obtaining this timestamp?

P.S. are you sure the year is set to 2013 on this machine and not to 4013? :) This would then fit with the .NET epoch of January 1, Year 1

Comment: The timestamps are generated by another piece of software. The date on the machine is correct ;-)  I think you are right about the minutes, I'll do some math to see if it works :-)

Answer (score 0):

In order to distinguish *your* timestamp from *Unix* timestamp, let's call yours *The Counter*.

So we have four counter values with their corresponding DateTime value. The first thing to do is calculate the counter's unit correspondence to a real time unit, let's say *a second*.

In order to do that, we need (1) the difference `d` between two counter values and (2) the difference `s` between their corresponding DateTimes, in seconds.

Considering the first two values we have `d1=2111441998-2111441659=339`. The difference between `2013-10-01 11:59` and `2013-10-01 17:14` (in seconds) is `s1=18900`. Consequently, the counter's unit corresponds to `u1=s1/d1=55.7522123894` seconds.

But if we do the same with pairs #2 and #3, we will find that `u2=40.9584664536` seconds.

Similarily, pairs #3 and #4 give us `u3=56.6197183114` seconds.

My conclusion therefore, is that there's no alignment between the counter values and the corresponding DateTimes provided. That's the reason why you get a different result with each sample.